# Qt :convert xml to html ( with help of xslt ) report

Tags: html, xml, qt, report, file-conversion

Greetings.
Wanted to convert xml , ( providing xslt and some images ) to html report using Qt ( 6.5 )
earlier versions had QxmlQuery to achieve that and it was achieved within 3-4 lines of code.
With latest versions , is it possible to do so ? Any equivalent clss or converter classes I can use ?

thanks & warm regards,
~ Rudresh

```
QFile myFile("D:/Report.xml");
if (!myFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
return -1 ;
               
QString contents = myFile.readAll();

QTextDocument qd (contents);

myFile.close();
          
QFile cssFile(      "Report.xslt");

cssFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
qd.setDefaultStyleSheet(cssFile.readAll());

//qd.setHtml(cssFile.readAll());

//QString html = qd.tr(cssFile.readAll());

qd.setHtml(contents);


QString html = qd.toHtml();

qDebug() << html ;


QFile outfile ("report.html");

if ( !outfile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly) )
    return -1 ;

QTextStream out(&outfile);

out << html ;

outfile.close();
```